# Need help adding code into JS using another JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script tag in a web-page which contains a function **updatevalues(value)**. I need to add code into that function using another javascript tag.

I am able to similarly write into other html elements by using getemementbyid.innerHTML...

How can i add code inside a JS function using another JS tag?

My current code is:

```
<script>
 function updatevalues(value){
       var a=1;
   }
</script>
```

I want to make it like this:

```
<script>
 function updatevalues(value){
       var a=1;
       var b=2;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Add your code or minimal working example. Your question is not clear.

Comment: What do you mean?? Do you want call another function in another file or what ?? Explain more !

Comment: In your case, you wont really need two different files. Just saying, you can put more than one functions in just one script tag

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to edit the previous `<script>`.  Literally just write this in a new `<script>`:

```js
function updatevalues(value) {
  var a=1;
  var b=2;
}
```

And it will override the definition of the same function in the previous script.

Comment: I do not want to change the original one. I want to change it using another script tag.